# Take sth into account vs. take into account sth

Tags: idioms, word-order

Regarding the idiom "take into account", when is it appropriate to put *something* between "take" and "into", and when is it best to place *something* at the end of the idiom?

For example, consider these sentences:

- We should take **money** into account in order to make a good decision.
- We should take into account **money** in order to make a good decision.
- We have to take into account **the fact that** money cannot be created out of thin air.
- We have to take **the fact that money cannot be created out of thin air** into account.
- We should take **his decision** into account.
- We should take into account **his decision**.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure there's a general rule. To me, it's just a matter of euphony.

Comment: Thanks! I found another answer to this question:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142024/take-something-into-account-vs-take-into-account-something-are-both-correc